Populate rows on different sheet based on cell value on other sheet
I have a master spreadsheet which contains all subjects e.g.

If value in column D is 'TRUE' I wish to populate row on second sheet with the first three columns e.g.

I could use this: =IF(Sheet5!D3=TRUE,Sheet5!A3," "), but that would leave blank rows for the rows that column D is 'FALSE'.
Is there a way to achieve this without the blank rows on the second sheet?

Does your version of Excel support the FILTER function?

I believe so, Microsoft Excel for Mac, Version 16.88

I want to give you some credit for a textbook way of asking a question. Way to give the ask in such a clear and concise way.

You can use a filter function for the table output. There's a combination of formulas you can do to reconstruct it the table, for example if you want to combine columns, or skip over specific ones. Since your table has all the columns adjacent I use a filter and selected the columns you wanted to have pulled and filtered off the last column.
=FILTER(A2:C4,D2:D4=TRUE)
And as BigBen mentioned, you can even drop the TRUE condition as the default knows to take this, but I'll keep the original in case you ever want to use something else like the FALSE condition or another value such as an age range.
=FILTER(A2:C4,D2:D4)

